# android: textView.setText when time 03.00 until 05.30

Tags: android, datetime

Okay i'm creating android apps and it related with time. example, 03.00 until 05.30 o'clock textView will setText 'good afternoon' else "good evening". Please share some solution, i was really confused with that algorithm, Thank you

Comment: We aren't going to write code for you.  Show us what you've tried and we'll help you to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a code that may solve your purpose.The concept is simple.Just take the time you want to validate from **Calendar class** and compare it with the **current time** and then take an appropiate action.

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 3);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

long noon_start = cal.getTimeInMillis();//3.00

cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 5);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);

long noon_end = cal.getTimeInMillis();//5.30
long now = System.currentTimeMillis();//current time

if(now > noon_start && now < noon_end)
{
    textView.setText("Good afternoon");
}
else
{
    textView.setText("Good Evening");
}
```

Comment: Awesome . . thank you kgandroid, yo make my life easy . .

Answer (score -1):

First you get time of device then you check condition

```
   if(time>=03:00 && time<=5:30){
    textview.setText("good afternoon");
     }else{
        textview.setText("good evevning");
      }
```